# Cannot GET/ Error In Node js With Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm working on node js backend which receives user sms from android app using telerivet webhook API.everytime when i run the app atheroku it gives me cannot GET/ error ,my code for index.js is

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

var WEBHOOK_SECRET = "62DZWMCCFFHTTQ44CG3WUQ94CTT7GAAN";

app.post('/telerivet/webhook', 
bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }),
function(req, res) {
  var secret = req.body.secret;
  if (secret !== WEBHOOK_SECRET) {
      res.status(403).end();
      return;
  }

  if (req.body.event == 'incoming_message') {

    var content = req.body.content;
    var from_number = req.body.from_number;
    var phone_id = req.body.phone_id;

    // do something with the message, e.g. send an autoreply
    res.json({
      messages: [
        { content: "Thanks for your message!,Our Backend Is Still in Alpha Stage,Hang Tight" }
      ]
    });

  }  

  res.status(200).end();
 }
 );

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

please help,where im i doing wrong
it gives me cannot GET/ error when i run the app on browser,and also doesnt reply for sms when testing with the app

Comment: You're requesting a root or "home" page, but haven't yet defined one -- `app.get('/', function ...);`.

Comment: can you elaborate it?if possible with the code to add? please

Comment: When you try to access `http://your-app.herokuapp.com/`, your browser sends a `GET` type request with the `/` path. Your application, however, hasn't defined how to respond to such a request, so Express is responding with [404 Not Found](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404). You can use [`app.get()` to respond to `GET` requests](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.METHOD). A simple example would be `app.get('/', function (req, res) { res.send('Hello'); });`. For more information, see [Express' guide on routing](http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html).

Comment: the code i specified is from telerivet documentation,they didnt specify any files/homepage.....and where this line of code points--app.post('/telerivet/webhook',

Comment: The `POST /telerivet/webhook` route may be all that telerivet requires. But, if you're trying to access your application in a browser, you're probably bypassing telerivet, placing more requirements on your application than just what the tool expects.

Comment: brother jonathen,i'm a noob in node js ,,,can you please modify the code i specified with your suggestion of including app.get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way out,this is my new code:

```
  var express = require('express');
  var app = express();

 app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
 app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

 app.get('/', function(request, response) {
 response.send('Hello World!');
 });

 var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

 var WEBHOOK_SECRET = "62DZWMCCFFHTTQ44CG3WUQ94CTT7GAAN";

 app.post('/telerivet/webhook', bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended:    true     }),function(req, res) {
    var secret = req.body.secret;
    if (secret !== WEBHOOK_SECRET) {
      res.status(403).end();
      return;
    }

    if (req.body.event == 'incoming_message') {

      var content = req.body.content;
      var from_number = req.body.from_number;
      var phone_id = req.body.phone_id;

    // do something with the message, e.g. send an autoreply
       res.json({
        messages: [
        { content: "Thanks for your message!,Stay Tuned for Awesome " }
      ]
    });

     }  

     res.status(200).end();
     }
      );

         app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
        console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
         });
```